# .setValue going to specific cell rather than the next row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For some reason, whenever I run this function, it first takes a very long time to execute but secondly always replaces in cell E9, rather than going to the next available cell (in this case E10).

This is my code:

```
    var RecruitRosterLastRow = RecruitRoster.getLastRow();
    
    var RecruitRosterRange = RecruitRoster.getRange(1,1,RecruitRosterLastRow,7);

    var RecruitRosterRangeValues = RecruitRosterRange.getValues();
  
    var RecruitRosterRow = 8;
    while (RecruitRosterRow <= RecruitRosterLastRow)

      {
      if (RecruitRosterRangeValues[RecruitRosterRow-1][1] == "")        // Is Website ID cell blank?
      {
        RecruitRoster.getRange(RecruitRosterRow, 5).setValue(AutomationSheet.getRange(asFTAddWebID).getValue()); // Add Website ID to website ID column on Recruit Roster
        RecruitRosterRow = RecruitRosterLastRow+1;
      }
      //Repeats if not
      else 
      {
        RecruitRosterRow++;
      }
    }
```

And this is my sheet:
[image: sheet]

If you need any additional screenshots or explanation, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Your code is not reproducible.  Please provide [mcve].  It's not java, or javascript either

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wish to go to the first blank in column 2

#### Find the column height of column 2

```
function getColumnHeight(col=2, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

After you get this value add one to it and go to that row.  This is the kind of issue that highlights the value of knowing how to code when you are designing a spreadsheet in a way that simplifies the code.